# What is a user session in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I came across some article while going through the msdn website about user session. Can anyone help me understand what is a user session in SQL Server? when is it established? And how can we know that?

Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Logon triggers fire in response to the LOGON event that is raised when
>   a user sessions is being established

Comment: @marc_s  thanks for the edit, do you know what is session in sql server, or is the concept of session really exists in sql server? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User session is internal SQL Server process with specific user context.
You can get all sessions with such query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1
```

User session established when client application opens new connection to SQL server.

Comment: if there are three users with the same username and password on the server, then it will create three session of the server, right?

Comment: @LijinJohn, the security context doesn't matter. A session is created for each user connection even when the same login is used.